# Can I add a style to an SCSS class based on the element the class in used on?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

In my Angular 13 project, I have a class I'm using on two types of elements: `<a>` tags and `<mat-panel-title>` tags. My question is, can I add a style to this class and do it in a way that it will only apply to the `a` tags and not the other ones.

this is the scss code:

```
.container__menu--item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    text-decoration: none;

    span {
      padding-inline-start: 8px;
    }
  }
```

and this is the html:

```
 <a class="container__menu--item" href="#">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    <span>{{ 'navbar.main_page' | transloco }}</span>
  </a>

  <mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title class="container__menu--item">
          <mat-icon svgIcon="services"></mat-icon>
          <span>{{ 'navbar.services' | transloco }}</span>
        </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {{ 'navbar.services' | transloco }}
        </li>
        <li>
          {{ 'navbar.services' | transloco }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @NathanielFlick oops sorry i'll add it now

Comment: `.container__menu--item:not(mat-panel-title)`? see [pseudo class not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do either

```
.container__menu--item {
    <shared style>

    a {
      <specific style>
    }
}
```

Or use two separate classes for the different elements but essentially copy the style of one to the other using `@extend`. This would for example look like

```
.container__menu--link {
    @extend .container__menu--item
 }
```

where `container__menu--link` is applied to the a tag and `container__menu--item` to mat-panel-title.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to apply styles to an `<a>` with the class `container__menu--item`, you simply could combine the selectors like `a.container__menu--item`:

```css
a.container__menu--item {
    ... /* your styles */
}
```

Comment: yeah I know that. i was wondering if there was a way to not add another ruleset and just include it in the one I had. thanks though.